# Is it correct to extend a bean class and write a class which holds logic to populate the bean we extend?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need to extract some metrics from ManagedBeans and store the collected metrics in an object bean.

The object bean is defined with member variables to hold the metrics. In this case, is it right to extend the ObjectBean and write the extractor class?

For example:

```
class ThreadMetricsBean {
    private long liveCount, daemonCount;

    public void record(long liveCount, long daemonCount) {
        this.liveCount = liveCount;
        this.daemonCount = daemonCount;
    }
}

// Here to avoid code redundancy I feel it's correct to extend the  ThreadMetricsBean class
// Am I wrong ?? 

class ThreadMetricsExtractor {
    private long liveCount, daemonCount;
    private ThreadMetricsBean bean = new ThreadMetricsBean();

    public void run() throws Exception{
        extractMetrics();
        recordToBean();
    }

    private void extractMetrics() {
        ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
        this.liveCount = threadMXBean.getThreadCount();
        this.daemonCount = threadMXBean.getDaemonThreadCount();
    }

    private void recordToBean() {
        bean.record(liveCount, daemonCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: @palacsint that was a typo mistake. Now I have corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would declare variables on separate lines.

   > ```
   > private long liveCount, daemonCount;
   > ```

   From *Code Complete, 2nd Edition*, p761:

   > **Use only one data declaration per line**
   >
   > [...]
   >
   > It’s easier to modify declarations because each declaration is self-contained.
   >
   > [...]
   >
   > It’s easier to find specific variables because you can scan a single
   >   column rather than reading each line. It’s easier to find and fix
   >   syntax errors because the line number the compiler gives you has 
   >   only one declaration on it.
2. The code has a temporal coupling here:

   > ```
   > public void run() throws Exception{
   >     extractMetrics();
   >     recordToBean();
   > }
   > ```

   A maintainer easily can change the order of the called methods which brokes it. See: *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *G31: Hidden Temporal Couplings*, p302
3. For this:

   > ```
   > // Here to avoid code redundancy I feel it's correct to extend 
   > // the  ThreadMetricsBean class
   > // Am I wrong ??
   > ```

   It's hard to say that which would be better without knowledge about clients and typical/possible usages of these classes. You might be able to remove redundancy in the following way too:

   ```
   class ThreadMetricsExtractor {
       private final ThreadMetricsBean bean = new ThreadMetricsBean();

       public void run() throws Exception {
           storeMetrics();
       }

       private void storeMetrics() {
           final ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
           final int liveCount = threadMXBean.getThreadCount();
           final int daemonCount = threadMXBean.getDaemonThreadCount();
           bean.record(liveCount, daemonCount);
       }
   }
   ```

   I've found that composition usually leads better design, cleaner and testable code than inheritance. A reference:  *Effective Java, Second Edition*, *Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance*.
4. The `throws Exception` is unnecessary here, as far I see nothing throws any checked exception inside the `run` method:

   > ```
   > public void run() throws Exception{
   >     extractMetrics();
   >     recordToBean();
   > }
   > ```
5. You could use integers here:

   > ```
   > this.liveCount = threadMXBean.getThreadCount();
   > this.daemonCount = threadMXBean.getDaemonThreadCount();
   > ```

   Both called methods returns `int`, so `liveCount` and `daemonCount` could be `int`s too.